# Chain rule on a dirac delta function

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I have the following expression that I would like to evaluate
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}\int_{y}\delta\left(f(x,y,\psi)\right)g(y)\,dy
$$

My question is whether the chain rule behaves well when differentiating distributions rather than functions (I should note that my understanding of the dirac delta as a distribution, and how to differentiate it at all, remains extrememly shallow - I am actively following on links [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/68732/what-is-the-first-derivative-of-dirac-delta-function), [here](http://web.mit.edu/8.323/spring08/notes/ft1ln04-08-2up.pdf) and [here](https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Delta%20Functions/Simplified%20Dirac%20Delta.pdf) to try and understand better).  Below I've written what I naively might think to do
$$
\int_{y}\frac{\partial}{\partial f}\delta\left(f(x,y,\psi)\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial \psi}g(y)\,dy
$$

I should note that the derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \psi}$ is easy to get hold of.  I should also note (though this may not be important) that $y$ is periodic and the integral over the domain of $y$ is actually only between $(-\pi, \pi]$.

Comment: I can see no problem with this. The Dirac $\delta$ can be approximated with ordinary functions for which the differentiation is valid, and then we just take limits.

Comment: SO your suggestion is to write this out as, for example, the gaussian distribution with the limit of $\sigma$ going to 0, and proceed like that?

Comment: You can do that, or just use the expression as you have it. I see no problem with that expression as long as $f$ is smooth.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  If you provide an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no problem with this as long as $f \in C^\infty.$ The Dirac $\delta$ can be approximated with ordinary functions for which the differentiation is valid, and then we just take limits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use that $\delta(f(x))=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{\delta(x-x_{i})}{|f'(x_{i}|}$ where $x_{i}$ is that $f(x_{i})=0$ and $f´(x_{i})\neq 0$ for more variables, don´t know the expression for that generalization of the property but maybe you can look it out